# Variable change over time based on event in R

Tags: r

I have some time lapsing data where I want to change specific variables based on an event. With help I was able to figure out how to change the value once, but I want to be able to change it constantly. Below is the data that I start out with.

```
Time Event1 Event2  ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_5
1    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
2    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
3    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
4    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
5    ID_2   ID_5    1    1    1    1    0
6    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
7    ID_5   ID_2    1    1    1    1    0
8    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
```

What I want to happen, is when an ID_X shows up in Event1, I want to change all future values in that variable to 0 UNTIL they show up again in Event2, in which case I want to flip them back to a 1. Below is what I am looking to do.

**UPDATED DATA TABLE**

```
Time Event1 Event2  ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_5
1    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
2    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
3    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
4    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
5    ID_2   ID_5    1    0    1    1    1
6    0      0       1    0    1    1    1
7    ID_5   ID_2    1    1    1    1    0
8    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
```

As you can see, ID_2 shows up in Event1, starts to get 0s, then shows up in Event2 and should be flipped back to 1. The only thing I was able to figure out with some help was how to flip it from 1/0 for the rest of the data. However, I don't think what I did (using melt and reshaping the data) will work when I need to change things back and forth. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using a combination of `cumsum()` to record appearances of `"ID_2"`, e.g., in `Event1` or `Event2`, resp., and `xor()` to flip.

```
library(data.table)
DT[, ID_2 := 0L + xor(cumsum(Event1 == "ID_2") - cumsum(Event2 == "ID_2"), ID_2)][]
DT[, ID_5 := 0L + xor(cumsum(Event1 == "ID_5") - cumsum(Event2 == "ID_5"), ID_5)][]
```

> ```
>     Time Event1 Event2 ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_5
>  1:    1      0      0    1    1    1    1    0
>  2:    2      0      0    1    1    1    1    0
>  3:    3      0      0    1    1    1    1    0
>  4:    4      0      0    1    1    1    1    0
>  5:    5   ID_2   ID_5    1    0    1    1    1
>  6:    6      0      0    1    0    1    1    1
>  7:    7   ID_5   ID_2    1    1    1    1    0
>  8:    8      0      0    1    1    1    1    0
>  9:    9   ID_2      0    1    0    1    1    0
> 10:   10      0      0    1    0    1    1    0
> 11:   11      0   ID_2    1    1    1    1    0
> 12:   12      0      0    1    1    1    1    0
> ```

Note that additional rows have been added to the sample data set in order to demonstrate that `ID_2` flips a second time.

If there are many `ID_x` columns, this can be repeated for each column conveniently using `lapply()`

```
id_cols <- stringr::str_subset(names(DT), "^ID")
invisible(lapply(id_cols, function(col) 
  DT[, (col) := 0L + xor(cumsum(Event1 == col) - cumsum(Event2 == col), get(col))]))
DT[]
```

The result is the same as above.

`data.table` is used because it allows to update single columns *in place*, i.e., without copying the whole data set which saves memory and time. `invisible()` prevents the result of `lapply()` to be printed. The result of `lapply()` is not needed here as `DT` is updated in place.

#### Prerequisites

The code is working for the given sample. It relies on the assumption that each `ID_x` appears alternating in `Event1` and `Event2` and is likely to fail otherwise.

#### EDIT: Check for prerequisites

The version below includes a check which halts execution if above prerequisite is violated (not the best self-explanatory error message, though):

```
id_cols <- stringr::str_subset(names(DT), "^ID")
invisible(lapply(id_cols, function(col) 
  DT[, (col) := {
    tmp <- cumsum(Event1 == col) - cumsum(Event2 == col)
    stopifnot(all(tmp %in% -1:1))
    0L + xor(tmp, get(col))
  }]))
DT[]
```

#### Data

As provided by the OP plus four rows added.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  "Time Event1 Event2  ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_5
  1    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
  2    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
  3    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
  4    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
  5    ID_2   ID_5    1    1    1    1    0
  6    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
  7    ID_5   ID_2    1    1    1    1    0
  8    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
  9    ID_2   0       1    1    1    1    0
 10    0      0       1    1    1    1    0
 11    0      ID_2    1    1    1    1    0
 12    0      0       1    1    1    1    0"
)
```